# How would one define polynomials over the projective line $P_K^1$

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

May $K$ be a field. If I set $\varXi=(X:Y)$ as a "projective variable" and "projective coefficients" $a_k=(x_k:y_k)\in P_K^1$ - may I then write a polynomial map $P_K^1\longrightarrow P_K^1$ in a form like

$$\sum_{k=0}^na_k\varXi^k$$

What is the form of the resulting $F(X,Y)$ ? A homogeneous polynomial ?

Comment: How do you define $\varXi^k$?

Comment: That is what i right now dont remember. E.g. to get the square of $\varXi$ i need the product in $P_K^1$ of $(X:Y)(X:Y)$

Comment: I would suggest when i Interpret the concept of rotations which Prof Wildberger introduced in his YouTube Video MF137 that $$(X:Y)(X:Y)=(X^2-Y^2:2XY)$$

Comment: The really worse task seems to be to define a summation on $P_k^1$. But to be able to define a polynomial the $P_k^1$ would have to be a ring - isnt it ? The multiplikation with coefficient constants $c_k$ from $K$ at least would be possible by identifying them with $a_k=(c_k:0)$. Then $e=(1:0)$ would be the identity element as must be as one easily calculates.

Comment: Yes, you need a ring structure, and I agree that defining addition seems tricky, too. Also, how do you define $(c_k : 0)(x:y)$? The only sensible thing I can think of is to define multiplication component-wise, but then you should use $(c_k : 1)$ instead, otherwise $(c_k : 0)(0:1) = (0:0) \notin \Bbb{P}^1_K$.

Comment: The multiplication is in analogy to the rotation composition that Prof Wildberger defined in $P_K^1$ simply the multiplication law of complex numbers. Means identify $(x:y)$ with $x+yi$. I read in the book of Coxeter that he constructed an "addition" but I dont grasp whether that is relevant here and how this construction might be translated into homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: I opened also a question here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212858/can-the-projective-line-be-provided-with-a-ring-structure?noredirect=1#comment527601_212858 Maybe the results there solve this question.

Comment: Indeed, they do: both answers tell you that it isn't possible to put a ring structure on $\Bbb{P}^1_{\Bbb{R}}$, thus you cannot define a polynomial function $\Bbb{P}^1_{\Bbb{R}} \to \Bbb{P}^1_{\Bbb{R}}$.

Comment: I had an idea: maybe on the $P_K^1$ the addition is to be set exactly the same as the multiplication ( because of the $\tan$-addition mentioned on the mathoverflow site ). Then I could write at least the polynomial formally and simplify it to some - not yet calculated by me - value: maybe some power of the variable $\varXi$.

Comment: From those same answers on MO you also learn that while you can put some group structure on $\Bbb{P}^1_K$, none of those is compatible with the topological structure on $\Bbb{P}^1_K$. This means that the resulting "polynomial" functions wouldn't be continuous (at least in general)!